# Acesso http via gson com parametros

Tags: android, gson

Na minha primeira investida em desenvolvimento android, me deparei com a seguinte necessidade. Preciso criar uma tela de login acessando o um endereço e capturando o retorno da gson abaixo. Como poderia fazer?

```
LOGIN URL: /api/auth/login Method: POST  
Data: {"login":"user","password":"1234"} 

Return: { 
result:  { 
success:  { 
USER_TOKEN: "6a89d26d7cc768b5e25c187d49c43a1bb2d46bf4 be561" SES_NAME_PERSON: "User" } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui utilizando o método abaixo

```
  public static String getJson(String serverUrl, String host, String jsonobject) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String http = serverUrl;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(http);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(50000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        urlConnection.connect();
        //You Can also Create JSONObject here
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonobject);// here i sent the parameter
        out.close();
        int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            Log.e("new Test", "" + sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            Log.e(" ", "" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```